# Or condition between Policy and Roles in Authorize attribute in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I apply Or condition between Policy and Roles in the AuthorizeAttribute? I need to expose an Action to the users which either belongs to some roles or satisfying a particular AuthorizationPolicy. I was trying to achieving this like

```
[Authorize(Policy = AuthorPolicyRequirementHandler.FooPolicy,Roles = RoleName.FooRoles)]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FOO(long id)
{
   return Ok();     
}
```

But this is applying the And condition. Is there any way to apply Or condition?